# Does the phrase "Tom has been seeing Mary for a while" always imply they have a romantic relationship?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to [the Oxford learner's dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/see_1?q=see), "**see somebody**" mean "to spend time with somebody". It does not say the 2 have a romantic relationship or not, so I reckon the 2 could be just friends or couples.

Say, Tom and Mary are just friends nothing more. They like to talk with each other, they they are never in love with each other.

Can we say "**Tom has been seeing Mary for a while**" in that situation?

Does the phrase "**Tom has been seeing Mary for a while**" always imply they have a romantic relationship?

To remove the confusion, do you think we just say "**Tom has been hanging out with Mary for a while**" or the likes?

Comment: My experience is that people's understanding of expressions relating to romance or sex is very strongly biased by their own personal experience and expectations, so unless you write a completely 100% explicit sentence, different people will always interpret it differently.

Comment: If Mary is a doctor, psychiatrist, or other personal service provider, Tom seeing Mary can also mean availing himself of her services regularly.

Comment: Since this site is for learning English, I point out that using "2" instead of "two" in this context is quite jarring. See [here](https://www.scribbr.com/academic-writing/numbers/) and [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/when-to-spell-out-numbers/) for citations.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Without any context, the sentence "Tom has been seeing Mary for a while" would strongly imply that they had a romantic relationship. In the dictionary entry that you cite, the only example that uses the progressive aspect of "see" with a person as the direct object is the first ("Are you seeing anyone"), and the dictionary notes that the meaning is "having a romantic relationship with anyone". It's quite unlikely that a listener would understand that "Tom and Mary are just friends nothing more".

However, if we knew that Mary was a psychotherapist, then your sentence would indicate that Tom had attended therapy sessions with her for a while. (This was suggested by gidds in a comment below.) Other meanings are also possible in other contexts.

Yes, you could say, "Tom has been hanging out with Mary for a while", but the verb "hang out" is more colloquial than "see". If you didn't want to change the tone so much, then a better option might be "[spend time with](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spend_time)".

Comment: If they are both young people - say 18 to 25, the more likely expression for a developing romance would be "Tom is going out with Mary". "Seeing" I believe gets used with older people - at least that's my UK sense.

Comment: @WS2 - Perhaps I'm a _very_ old person, but my impression is that _seeing someone_ meaning 'in a romantic relationship with them' is a _comparatively_ recent usage!

Comment: @KateBunting - when I started having anything to do with the opposite sex, around 1968, if a regular arrangement ensued it was definitely called 'going out with'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Exactly. I would have said it was older than 'seeing'.

Comment: As an illustration of why this may not be true in specific contexts, consider that Mary may be a psychoanalyst, and so Tom's ‘seeing her’ may consist of sessions of psychoanalysis, and their relationship would be entirely professional. Or Mary could be providing some other service, such as hairdressing or dentistry or accountancy or music lessons. — However, _without_ knowing any such context, a romantic relationship would be a reasonable assumption.

Comment: @gidds Yes, exactly! I had a different example of how "seeing someone" could have a different meaning (though I decided not to include it), but the psychoanalyst example is perfect. I suspect that the understood genders (based on the names) could provide some of that context, too.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it could also be literal, given the right context: "Tom loves creepily watching people with binoculars from his balcony without their knowledge. He's been seeing Mary for a while."

What it *cannot* mean is that they're platonic friends who frequently hang out together.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Feel free to edit some or all of that into your answer. (Making the best answers is our collective goal!)

Comment: @gidds That's definitely correct. If the context is that Mary is a doctor and Tom is her patient, then this sentence would simply imply that he's been her patient for a while, with no romantic implication. However, the answer is still correct as written that, without further context, the sentence does indeed imply a romantic relationship.

Comment: @gidds Done, thanks!

Comment: You may be right there. And I think it probably began as an expression of an illicit relationship. "Does his wife know he's seeing someone from work?" But it definitely gets used with people in older age who have been widowed or made otherwise single - "Geoff seems a lot happier than he was, I think he may be seeing someone".

Comment: @neminem, wouldn't that be more like "looking" or indeed "watching", or perhaps "focusing on"? Or course you also "see" if you look or watch, but then also Tom might have just "seen" Mary walk on the other side of the yard with both minding their business, just like everyone sees dozens of people daily. But I don't think that was the meaning. Then again, I wonder, why couldn't it mean a platonic friendship? If Tom can "see" a therapist without a romantic connection, why couldn't he "see" someone he just likes the company of? (Or is it that we assume a male and a female can't be just friends?)

Comment: @WS2 I’d say that most 18–25-year-olds would probably find it rather old-fashioned to say that they’re ‘going out with’ someone. _Seeing_, I think, originated in the US and entered the UK some time in the not-too-distant past, and I think younger Brits would be even more likely to use an even more recently borrowed Americanism and say they’re _dating_. My gut feeling is that ‘dating’ is a less old-fashioned equivalent of ‘going out with’, and ‘seeing’ is a less old-fashioned equivalent of ‘going steady with’ (implying a more serious, established relationship), but it’s obviously very fuzzy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Odd. In my experience "seeing" is something widowed octogenarians do.

Comment: While the romantic meaning is the one to choose without context, it is fun to conceive of different contexts. In general terms, Mary is visible to Tom but not necessarily vice versa: Mary may be an approaching lion, or a sniper's target, or a spaceship about to dock on the ISS.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on context "seeing" could be in a professional capacity i.e. Mary is a psychiatrist, doctor, hairdresser, personal trainer, etc.

However, lacking additional context, I would assume romantically, as it is the most common usage.

Comment: When would a client or patient refer to a professional/doctor by only their first name? It's more likely "I'm seeing Dr. Baker this morning" followed by "I've been seeing him for a while" You would have to be long term friends with a dentist, family physician (etc.)  to be on first names basis.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Pick a profession that's associated with less formality, then.  Hairdresser, life coach, personal trainer, piano teacher, etc. still have one-on-one sessions with clients.  Easy to imagine someone preferring to be professionally known by their first name in some of those fields.

Comment: @PeterCordes How often would anyone say about their hairdresser "I've been seeing Mary for a while?" Its more likely "Mary's been cutting my hair/giving me piano lessons/teaching me for a while“ If you began saying "I've been seeing Mary for a few months" 99% people will presume a romantic relationship.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yeah, without context, romantic is the default meaning.  For a context where another meaning is clear, imagine 2 people chatting, one recommending a hairdresser to another.  The phrase "I've been seeing Mary for a while" could easily come up after the subject of hairdressing is established.  Or a third person chiming in that they've also been seeing Mary after the subject of Mary as a hairdresser has been raised, as an implicit recommendation, not as a statement about their love life.

Comment: In that scenario "She's been cutting/styling my hair for some time (a while)" is more likely but lest we forget, the OP wrote **Tom has been seeing Mary for a while** = dating

Comment: @Mari-LouA  The original question revolved around: "Tom has been seeing Mary for a while"  If I was married to a Doctor called Mary, and was talking to my sister for example, the lack of formality would be totally normal.

Comment: @MikeB where in the question does it suggest that Mary might be a doctor? There are all sorts of situations that one could conjure up, but for *learners* it's best to stick to the most likely scenarios, because these will be the most useful and practical for everyday life. But as they say,  YMMV.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  That was the entire point of this particular answer.

Comment: @MikeB  IMO the premise is given prominence when it could've been added as a footnote. The OP in the question asked about using "seeing someone" in a non-romantic relationship between *friends*. It's irrelevant if the friend is a dentist, a doctor or your probation officer. Can I say “I'm seeing Jon“ without the listener thinking I am speaking romantically? I see no mention what two friends (Tom and Mary) would say to each other. The author, colintd, can edit and improve their answer or just leave it as is. Receiving 13 upvotes is a good measure of consensus, it just doesn't include mine.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "seeing" means "having a romantic relationship with". Well, unless the context calls for it to be taken literally. Like, "Once he got new glasses, Tom could see Mary."

If you wanted to say that they were friends but not romantically involved, you could say, "Tom and Mary are friends" or "Tom and Mary spend a lot of time together."

But note that the idiom "sees a lot of", like, "Tom sees a lot of Mary lately", does NOT necessarily indicate a romantic relationship. You could say, "Since they both started working for the same company, Tom and Mary see a lot of each other."